# 2 containers cancel eachother

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i would like to know how i can prevent two containers from canceling. the codes are almost the same i just changed a few things it doesn't mater which one i put first but the second one is not working if i switched them around the one that i put first works but not the second one. I'm using toggle to display one at a time. I'm just going to post a small part of my code.

JavaScript for first part

```
<script>
var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
/** Make div draggable **/
$('<div />', {
    class: 'ui-widget-content',
    appendTo: '.container',
    draggable: {
        containment: 'parent',
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
        }
    }
});
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text', function()
{
$(this).hide();    $(this).closest('.item').find('.edit_text').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text", function()
{
return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function()
{
var editingText = $('.edit_text:visible');
if (editingText.length)
{
    editingText.hide();
    editingText.closest('.item').find('.text').text($(editingText).val()).show();
}
});


var count = 1;
var selectedDraggable;

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    $(element).draggable();
    $(element).addClass('item' + count);
    count++;
    $(element).on('click', function () {
        selectedDraggable = $(this);
    })
}
};


var vm=function(){
var self=this;
self.items=ko.observableArray();
self.textContent = ko.observable('');
self.init=function(){
    self.items([]);
}
self.remove=function(item){
    console.log(item);
    self.items.remove(item);
}
self.addNew = function() {
  self.items.push( self.textContent() );
  self.textContent('');
}
self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

JavaScript for second part

```
var z = 1; //value to make div overlappable

$('#addText').click(function (e) {
/** Make div draggable **/
$('<div />', {
    class: 'ui-widget-content',
    appendTo: '.container4',
    draggable: {
        containment: 'parent',
        start: function( event, ui ) {
            $(this).css('z-index', ++z);
        }
    }
});
});


$(document).on("dblclick", '.text1', function()
{
$(this).hide();    $(this).closest('.item1').find('.edit_text1').val($(this).text()).show();
});

$(document).on("click", ".edit_text1", function()
{
return false;
});


$(document).on("click", function()
{
var editingText = $('.edit_text1:visible');
if (editingText.length)
{
    editingText.hide();
    editingText.closest('.item1').find('.text1').text($(editingText).val()).show();
}
});


var count = 1;
var selectedDraggable;

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    $(element).draggable();
    $(element).addClass('item1' + count);
    count++;
    $(element).on('click', function () {
        selectedDraggable = $(this);
    })
}
};


var vm=function(){
var self=this;
self.items1=ko.observableArray();
self.textContent1 = ko.observable('');
self.init=function(){
    self.items1([]);
}
self.remove=function(item){
    console.log(item);
    self.items1.remove(item);
}
self.addNew1 = function() {
  self.items1.push( self.textContent1() );
  self.textContent1('');
}
self.init();
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

toggle

```
 $("#show_first").click(function(){
 $(".firstdiv").toggle();
 $(".seconddiv").hide();
 });

$("#show_second").click(function(){
 $(".secoddiv").toggle();
 $(".firstdiv").hide();
});
```

HTML for toggle

```
<button type="button" id="show_first">Display Front</button>
<button type="button" id="show_second">Display Back</button>
```

HTML for container and input text (first)

```
<div class="firstdiv"><center>Front</center>
<div class="container1" style=" float: left;" >
<p align="center"><textarea data-bind="value: textContent" Placeholder="Type text to append" rows="4" cols="21"></textarea>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: addNew">Create</button></p>
<div id="box" class="container" style="float:left;">

 <div data-bind="foreach:items" class="fix_backround">
<div class="item" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">

    <center><span class="text" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text"/></center></div></div></div></div></div>
```

HTML for container and input text (second)

```
<div class="seconddiv"><center>second</center>
<div class="container3" style=" float: left;" >
<p align="center"><textarea  data-bind="value: textContent1" Placeholder="Type text to append" rows="4" cols="21"></textarea>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <button type="button" data-bind="click: addNew1">Create</button></p></div>

<div id="box1" class="container4" style="float:left;">

  <div data-bind="foreach:items1" class="fix_backround1">
  <div class="item1" data-bind="draggable:true,droppable:true">

    <center><span class="text1" data-bind="text:$data"></span><input class="edit_text1"/></center></div></div></div></div></div>
```

Script

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet"href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

 <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 <script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script><script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are including jQuery, Knockout, and jQuery-UI each twice. That's probably not the problem, but it's not good.

You're using jQuery to control which block displays, and that's a Knockout no-no. It is Knockout's job to manipulate the DOM. Have a look at [Knockout templates](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html), or the [`if` binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/if-binding.html) for ways of controlling what displays.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in your toggle js for the seconddiv class. You're missing an 'n' in your jquery call for it: `secoddiv`. If this code is straight from the source that may be the problem.

Comment: I changed the name of the div so it could make sense its actually backdiv

Comment: It would help if you could assemble a fiddle so I could see it in action.