# ko.js twice in a page

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

Is it possible to have two ko.js in a page? they have different class and id. If it's possible what code do I need to use to have them work together at the moment one of the coded are not working it is being over shadowed by the first one

Comment: Do you mean two viewmodels? Two sections of HTML managed by Knockout? Can you explain more about what you're trying to do?

Comment: I have two html managed by knockout when I put them in the same page one is overshadowed by by the first one. Sorry i didnt explain myself

Comment: I think we're going to need to see some code that demonstrates what you mean by "overshadowed". Can you make a minimal Fiddle (or snippet here) that has the problem?

Comment: @RoyJ Here are my previous  question take a look at this  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755279/2-containers-cancel-eachother

Comment: BAsically the first code works and the second one witchever one it is does not work it's impossible to type and post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I see from your [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38755279/2-containers-cancel-eachother) you have 2 view models and you want to apply them to different elements in the HTML.

You can call the applyBindings method with a second parameter- the HTMl element on which you want to apply your view model.

```
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel1, $('.firstdiv').get(0))
 ko.applyBindings(viewModel2, $('.seconddiv').get(0))
```

*If the two views/HTML elements are nested one in other you have to use a [skipBinding](http://www.knockmeout.net/2012/05/quick-tip-skip-binding.html).*